# Is there a way to install Latex, Sage and Gap on a Chromebook?

Tags: latex, sage, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I just acquire a HP Chromebook 14", and I know it's limited for the installation of new applications.

I would like to install  [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/), [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) and [Gap](http://www.gap-system.org/) on it (and also some packages), but I did not find them on [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore).

Note that I've found online applications for Latex and Sage (not for Gap), but I'm looking for applications available directly on the laptop (via a terminal for Sage and Gap), not via internet.

If what I'm looking for doesn't exist yet, are there people working on such applications, or can I ask Google for the introduction of such applications?

Comment: As for the GAP system, could you please post this question in the [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can compile and use Sage in a chrooted linux install on a chromebook (requires developer mode). E.g. using crouton (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton). Another possibility is to just install linux directly, though I suppose that is not what you are asking for.

The sandbox for native chrome apps (i.e. NaCl) is too restrictive for Sage and many other standard unix applications. In particular, you can't fork new processes.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like at least some people have successfully built Sage on a Chromebook, running Ubuntu.  (Not necessarily running the Chrome OS.)

However, see [Trac 14689](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14689) for a possible current problem.

Also, since you may have an Intel chip, not an ARM one, maybe that won't be a problem anyway.  But I do think you'd have to compile from source at this time (I'd be glad to be proved wrong).

Answer (score 2):

You can run GAP on cloud.sagemath.org, as it, among other things, gives you a terminal environment.